# Elasticsearch as DB or Elasticsearch over MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

not sure that question belongs to this "stack" but here we go...

My use case is to provide a full text search on a large amount of data. New data is being added all the time.

I know Elasticsearch will search fast quickly, but I don't know if Elasticsearch as a NoSQL database (to simply store the data) will have better performance compared to storing the data in MongoDB and index the MongoDB using Elasticsearch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some answers to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723239/elasticsearch-v-s-mongodb-for-filtering-application + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538527/mongodb-elasticsearch-or-only-elasticsearch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**
It is perfectly good to use it as primary storage if you don't need ACID compliant database. Do backups.

[There is an answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-2-3-as-primary-data-store/50265/3) on this often asked question from Elastic team

> Some key points first:
>
> - We do not advertise Elasticsearch as a primary data store but many customers are using it as a primary data store.
> - Elasticsearch is an eventually consistent, near-realtime storage engine.
> - Elasticsearch is not ACID compliant like a database.

[This page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html) has current status of issues you can face

It also depends on other features you have in your system.

I have experience using Elasticsearch as primary data storage on high traffic web site for several years. It works very good.