# Mongodb vs elastic search for non-full-text search

Tags: mongodb, search, elasticsearch

I am making an  website that use mongoDB to store product information.
I want to use elastic search to let user search products by name or description.

However, I also want to let user search products by their category, regions... (which is not full text search).

In that case, should i also use elastic search or normal mongoDB query for search? Is there any benefit elastic search can bring to the table when the search is not full-text search.

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch is not only useful for [full-text search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html), but also for [term-level search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html) (i.e. exact search), [geo search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-queries.html), ... and of course [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

If you need any of this, then ES is worth investigating. Also, you should not necessarily take the "either-or" stance, you can definitely use both in conjunction as they are complimentary.

There are a few other answers worth looking at:

- [elasticsearch v.s. MongoDB for filtering application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723239/elasticsearch-v-s-mongodb-for-filtering-application/12733419#12733419)
- [How to use Elasticsearch with MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb/25714799#25714799)

Comment: Did this help ?