# MongoDB vs ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose

I am using MongoDB to store data but it doesn't have inbuilt mechanism for partial Search. Shall i use Elasticsearch instead ? I am having user related data who can publish posts and videos.

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723239/elasticsearch-v-s-mongodb-for-filtering-application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch v.s. MongoDB for filtering application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723239/elasticsearch-v-s-mongodb-for-filtering-application)

Comment: Have  you looked at MongoDB Atlas Search? https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/search-a

Answer (score 0):

In short:

elasticsearch -> distributed search engine for full text search
mongoDB       -> document store for reliable distributed storage

Conclusion:
elasticsearch on top of mongoDB make your document database search solution complete

Comment: How to do that . I mean Elasticsearch on top of mongoDB